# Laravel 5 e Sql Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

Preciso de um help, eu fiz várias tentativas de conectar o Laravel com o SQL Server e todas sem sucesso. Porém, consegui fazer funcionar com php puro, utilizando sqlsrv_connect e Code Igniter.

```
Windows 10 64 bits.
Wampserver 2.5 32 bits.
PHP version: 5.5.12 (TS, no php info: Thread Safety enabled).
PHP Extension: Build    API20121212, TS, VC11.
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Estou tentando conectar num db que já existe em rede fora do meu computador de desenvolvimento, mas em todo o caso, vai print do meu sql server manager:

[image: Sql Server Configuration Manager]
[image: Configurações no php info]

Já tentei conectar só com o name do server em vez do "ip, porta".
Tentei fazer um connect puro com new PDO e não deu certo, a mensagem que
retorna é de "could not find driver". E no Laravel o erro é igual:
"PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver".

Dei umas debugadas e vi que o código pára no "createConnection" do file:

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php

E o código pára exatamente onde tenta fazer o new PDO:

```
try{
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}catch(Exception $e){
  $pdo = $this->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(
    $e, $dsn, $username, $password, $options
  );
}

return $pdo;
```

Imagino que apesar de eu estar conseguindo utilizar com o sqlsrv_connect (Code Igniter faz conexão assim em vez de por PDO??) há algum erro de configuração, ou na .dll do arquivo me impedindo de utilizar o PDO.

Arquivo de configuração  **.env**:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=[a key da aplicação tá okay]

DB_HOST=[IP,PORT]
DB_DATABASE=[nome do banco de dados]
DB_USERNAME=[usuário]
DB_PASSWORD=[senha]

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Arquivo **database.php**:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
'connections' não mexi, está ~original~:
'sqlsrv' => [
  'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
  'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'charset'  => 'utf8',
  'prefix'   => '',
],
```

Arquivo **"puro"** de conexão PDO que dá erro:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', true);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  try{
    $hostname = "IP, Porta";
    $dbname = "nome do banco";
    $username = "usuário do banco";
    $pw = "senha do banco";
    $pdo = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Erro de Conexão " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }

  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbo.USUARIOS");
  $query->execute();

  for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
    echo $i." - ".$row['Coluna']."<br/>";
  }
?>
```

> Erro exibido: Erro de Conexão could not find driver.

Arquivo **"puro"** de conexão PDO que dá erro:

```
<?php
      ini_set('display_errors', true);
      ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
      error_reporting(E_ALL);

      try{
        $hostname = "IP, Porta";
        $dbname = "nome do banco";
        $username = "usuário do banco";
        $pw = "senha do banco";
        $pdo = new PDO ("sqlsrv:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
      }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Erro de Conexão " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        exit;
      }

      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbo.USUARIOS");
      $query->execute();

      for($i=0; $row = $query->fetch(); $i++){
        echo $i." - ".$row['Coluna']."<br/>";
      }
?>
```

> Esse arquivo onde só troco o mssql por sqlsrv dá o seguinte erro: Erro
>   de Conexão SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An invalid keyword 'host' was specified in
>   the DSN string.

**UPDATE**

PDO com php puro já está funcionando, deixei ele igual a chamada do método utilizada pelo Laravel:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  try{
    // $hostname = "OLIMPO\SQLSERVER_DESENV";
    $port     = "NUMPORTA";
    $hostname = "IPDOSERVER".",".$port;
    $user     = "USERNAME";
    $senha    = "PASSWORD";
    $dbase    = "DBName";

    $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$hostname};Database={$dbase}", "{$user}", "{$senha}");
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Erro de Conexão " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.USUARIOS";
  foreach($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

  unset($pdo);
  unset($sql);
?>
```

> Agora é descobrir o que está acontecendo no Laravel porque na verdade
>   o objetivo de tudo isso era utilizar o Laravel em vez do CodeIgniter
>   para desenvolver a aplição:

[image: Erro no Laravel]

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31707/discussion-between-marcos-regis-and-anitachiele).

Answer (score 3):

Bem, primeiro você precisa dos drivers PDO do `php_pdo_sqlsrv`, que não são os mesmos que `php_sqlsrv`. Depois você tem que colocar o `sqlsrv` para ser o driver no Lavarel.

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
                'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
                'host'     => 'IPdoServidor',
                'database' => 'BancoDeDados',
                'username' => 'Usuario',
                'password' => 'Senha',
                'prefix'   => '',
            ),
```

Em **PHP.INI** na pasta do PHP, você tem que colocar uma nova extensão: `php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts` ou `php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts` (onde "55" se refere a versão 5.5 do PHP).

Verifique se na pasta ext do  PHP tem alfguma extensão sqlsrv_pdo. Se sim, na php.ini aponte para ela: `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll`. Se não, [baixe os drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098), salve na pasta ext do PHP e aponte para os drivers como no exemplo.

Comment: Olá.
Em Host eu coloco o IP do Servidor mas e a Instancia?
Como que eu faço?
Obrigado.