# Invalid handle returned - Conexão Laravel com SQL Server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estava desenvolvendo uma aplicação com o Laravel 5.5 com um banco de dados Mysql. Tudo estava funcionando normalmente, porém, agora o banco foi modificado para SQL Server.

Quando eu realizo o teste, volta o erro "Invalid handle returned."

- Pesquisando, vi que poderia ser a versão do meu php, então troquei a mesma, estava usando a 7.1 e agora estou na 7.0.23
- Todos os drivers (inclusive o pdo_sqlsvr) estão baixados e setados corretamente (php.ini e pasta ext)
- Microsoft ODBC instalado
- Todas as regras de firewall do sql server estão configuradas e liberadas

Meu arquivo .env está setado o seguinte:

```
APP_NAME=Incorptech
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=[key da aplicação está ok]
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=[host está ok]
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=[nome do banco]
DB_USERNAME=[usuario do banco]
DB_PASSWORD=[senha do banco]
```

O `database.php` está com as seguintes configurações:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
  'sqlsrv' => [
  'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
  'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
  'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
  'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'nomedobanco'),
  'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'usuario'),
  'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'senha'),
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'prefix' => '',
],
```

A função que eu estou realizando o teste e que este erro está voltando, é a seguinte:

```
public function testeDB() {
  $select = DB::select('select * from conta');
  return $select;
}
```

No prompt de comando do artisan, aparece o seguinte erro:

> PHP Fatal error: Invalid handle returned in
>   ...vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php
>   on line 67

A função da linha 67 do erro acima (essa função é do próprio laravel), no arquivo `\Connectors\Connector.php` é o seguinte:

```
protected function createPdoConnection($dsn, $username, $password, 
    $options) {
  if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
    return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
  }
  return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

Comecei a desenvolver em Laravel a pouco tempo, tem algo a mais a ser criado para essa conexão com o SQL Server ser efetuada com sucesso?

Comment: Talvez isto ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98544/laravel-5-e-sql-server

Comment: E aí Miguel, tudo bom? Antes de postar, eu pesquisei e olhei sim este artigo, mas no meu caso, eu não tenho nenhuma classe de php puro criando esta conexão PDO. Minha dúvida é justamente essa, com o MySQL, eu não precisei fazer nada disso manualmente, mas com o SQL Server eu tô meio perdido

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência com este problema, não te consigo ajudar por experiência própria porque nunca me conectei a essa base de dados. Mas há uma serie de links pelo google que te ajudar, ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428531/laravel-5-2-connect-to-ms-sql-2012

Answer (score 2):

Acabei conseguindo resolver o problema.

No SQL Server Configuration manager, em "Configuração de Rede do SQL Server", o protocolo TCP/IP estava habilitado, porém na aba "Endereços IP", o campo da porta estava em branco. Quando preenchi com a porta 1433, o problema foi resolvido.